# Proving vector subspaces are equal and intersection between vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I am having a bit of troubles with my linear algebra homework, question is as follows:

Assume $\mathbb{U_1\cap U=\{0\}}$ and $\mathbb{U_2\cap U=\{0\}}$, are  the following statements true or false?

1. if $\mathbb{U_1 \oplus U=U_2 \oplus U}$ then $\mathbb{U_1=U_2}$
2. $\mathbb{(U_1+U_2)\cap U = \{0\}}$

My attempts are as following:

1. $\mathbb{U_1 \oplus U}$ is this set {$\mathbb{u_1 + u |u_1 \in U_1 \land u \in U}$} and $\mathbb{U_2 \oplus U}$ is this set {$\mathbb{u_2 + u |u_2 \in U_2 \land u \in U}$}, if these two sets are equal then surely it must mean that $\mathbb{U_1=U_2}$ because it means all $\mathbb{u_1}$ equals all $\mathbb{u_2}$ but I am not sure if it is correct logic and if it is true.
2. $\mathbb{U_1+U_2}$ is the following set {$\mathbb{u_1 + u_2 |u_1 \in U_1 \land u_2 \in U_2}$}, the intersection of this set with $\mathbb{U}$ isn't necessarily $\mathbb{\{0\}}$, like, if $\mathbb{U}$ is this subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$ - $\mathbb{\{(x, x) | x\in R\}}$ and $\mathbb{U_1=\{(x, 0) | x\in R\}}$ and $\mathbb{U_2=\{(0, y) | y\in R\}}$ then take $\mathbb{(1,0)}$ from $\mathbb{U_1}$ and $\mathbb{(0,1)}$ from $\mathbb{U_2}$ and the addition of those two vectors is in $\mathbb{U}$. So this statement is false.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This statement is false. Take $\Bbb U=\{(x,0)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$, $\Bbb U_1=\{(x,x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$ and $\Bbb U_2=\{(0,x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$. Then $\Bbb U\cap\Bbb U_1=\Bbb U\cap\Bbb U_2=\{0\}$ and $\Bbb U_1\oplus\Bbb U=\Bbb U_2\oplus\Bbb U$, but $\Bbb U_1\ne\Bbb U_2$.
2. Your answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much!